# If conditions Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

all my values are int in my data frame and I am trying to do this if condition

if the value is greater than 1, than multiply by 1 else multiple the value with -1 and add to a new column, but it gives error

```
'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

below is the code I wrote

```
Cfile["Equ"] = [i*1 if i>1 else i*-1 for i in Cfile["Net Salary"]]
```

Comment: It works for me. Did you check all values are int with `Cfile["Net Salary"].dtype`?

Comment: i is supposed to be a float or an integer? Are you on windows and opening a file with commas instead of points to describe floats?

Comment: BTW, `Cfile["Equ"] = Cfile["Net Salary"].apply(lambda x: x if x>1 else -1*x)`

Comment: Thanks, I checked my Dataframe type and it was type O, I noticed at one place a letter was added which was causing the issue. Which solved my problem, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
s = df['Net Salary']
df['Equ'] = np.where(s.gt(1), s, s.mul(-1))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Use from this code:

```py
df['new'] = (df.net>1)*df.net - (1≥df.net)*df.net
```